# Выровнять элементы div и текст в них

Tags: html, css

Не получается выровнять несколько блоков и текст в них , уже пробовал display : inline-block и другими способами , но постоянно элемент, в котором длинный текст съезжает и никак не выравнивается, помогите выровнять все блоки и элементы в них по центру по вертикали и горизонтали

```css
nav.menu div {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 2px;
  background-color: #889fd6;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 55px;
  width: 165.7px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="">
    <div>Текст</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div>Текст</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div>Текст Текст Текст Текст</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div>Текст Текст</div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ну, для начала, `<div>` - блочный элемент, а `<a>` - сточной, поэтому не желательно, чтобы `<div>` был внутри `<a>`

Comment: @СемушинСергей, не просто не желательно. Согласно спецификации, это не валидно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  padding: 4px;
  flex-basis: 60px;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 2px;
  background-color: #889fd6;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 55px;
  width: 165.7px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div><a href="">Текст</a></div>
  <div><a href="">Текст</a></div>
  <div><a href="">Текст Текст Текст Текст</a></div>
  <div><a href="">Текст Текст</a></div>
</nav>
```